# What is faster and less in memory in Java: int[] or boolean[]?

Tags: java, arrays, performance

In Java, what is faster and less in memory: `int[n]` or `boolean[n]` or maybe `Bitset(n)` ?

The question is applicable for arrays of small (`n` is up to `1000`), medium (`n` is between `1000` and `100000`) and huge (`n` is greater than `100000`) sizes. Thank you.

I want to achieve flags (1/0) storage.

Comment: It depends what you are actually representing, and what you are doing with the representation.

Comment: And in the case of `int[]`, HOW you are representing them (assuming that you are talking about an array of "flags").

Comment: `int[] a = new int[n];` and then fill it in as `a[i] = 1`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On most JVMs; an array or object has a 12-16 byte overhead.  An `int` use 4 bytes and a `boolean` uses a byte (it doesn't have to but it does with OpenJDK/HotSpot)  BitSet uses two objects and more memory for small sets, but only one bit per have. So for small collections an `int[]` can be smaller than a `BitSet` but as the size grows, BitSet will be the smallest.

If the data structure is smaller than your cache the fastest is `int[]` then `boolean[]` then `BitSet` This is because there is non-trival overhead in breaking `int` into `byte` or a bit.

However once your cache size becomes important, it can be that the overhead of BitSet fades compared to the overhead of using a slower cache or main memory.

In short: if in doubt use BitSet as this is clearer as to your intent and its likely to be faster.

Answer (score 1):

Actually, it is JVM dependent. For example Sun JVM converts `boolean` type to `int`. That mean even boolean variable uses 32 bit. But jvm optimize boolean arrays, and reserve 8 bit per boolean array cell.

Answer (score 0):

Java store `boolean` as `int` internally. So `int[]` and `boolean[]` is exactly the same.

`BitSet` use less memory. Faster or not depends on your usage pattern.

Comment: And you are making a different set of assumptions to Azodious

Answer (score 0):

Descending order in memory usage

```
int[n] > Bitset(n) > boolean[n]
```

However, in accessing the indexes, there should not be any difference.

Answer (score 0):

Consider to replace bit flags with enums. Then you can use e.g. EnumSet instead of Bitset.